# nodeunit fail to exit from my asynchronous tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, integration-testing, nodeunit

**Whenever I run my nodeunit test in IDE or console,  it run well but fail to exit.  Help me please with it!**

```
var store = require('../lib/db');
var list = require('../source/models/mock_deals');
var logger = require('../lib/logging').logger;

exports.setUp = function(done){
    logger.info('start test...');
    done();
};
exports.tearDown = function(done){
    logger.info('end test...');
    done();
};

exports.testInsertDeal = function(test){
    var length = list.length;
    test.equals(length, 2);
    store.mongodb.open(function(err,db){
        if(err){
            logger.error(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.info("mongodb is connected!");

        db.collection('deals',function(err,collection){
            for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
                var item = list[i];
                collection.insert(item, function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        logger.error('Fail to insert document deal [' + item.id + ']');
                        return;
                    }
                    logger.info( 'index ' + i + ' : ' +JSON.stringify(item) );
                });
            }
        });
        test.expect(1);
    });
    test.done();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed to use **mongoose** instead of **mongodb**.  test still could not exit automatically.

But when I disconnected mongoose in `test.tearDown` method in my **nodeunit** test. the test existed correctly.

Add below in you test:

```
exports.tearDown = function(done){
    mongoose.disconnect(function(err){
        if(err) {
            logger.error(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.info('mongoose is disconnected');
    });
    done();
};
```

And more, If I use **log4js** for logging in my test and configure **log4js** with `reloadSecs: 500` , test will not exist either. After I set `reloadSecs` to 0, then test exists well. So we need to configure logging.json with option `reloadSecs: 0`

**To summarize: we need to make sure there are no working parts there after all test methods are done. then test will exist correctly.**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to call done() within the callback for disconnect?  Then you can be sure disconnect finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you know when your program should exit, you can simply use the following line of code to exit:

```
process.exit(0);
```

where 0 is the return code of the program.

Now that isn't really fixing the problem.  There is probably a call back still waiting or a connection that is still active keeping your program up and running that isn't shown in the code you posted here.  If you don't care to find it, just use process.exit.  If you really care to find it, you will have to dig some more.  I've never used nodeunit but I have used other node libraries that leave stuff up in their inner workings that keep the program from exiting.  In those cases, I usually don't feel like wading through other peoples source code to find out what is going on so I just do the afore mentioned process.exit call.

This should at least give you an option.

Comment: your answer reminded me. There is still some working code in my tests after my test is done.